# Facebook api message thread url framing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to frame url to open a message threads in facebook from my app.
Logic to frame the url is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051642/how-to-get-message-thread-url-knowing-the-thread-id)!

Problem is with the thread_id value which i am getting from facebook graph api. Thread_id which i get is always an integer value (for example 311135682316044). So that resulting view url is:

https://www.facebook.com/messages/?action=read&tid=id.311135682316044

But this link gives the error "message not found"!

I noticed that the url which facebook uses for the same htread has the thread_id value as string(for example da4fe83e8be749c75cb08275e95da47138)

http://www.facebook.com/messages/?action=read&tid=da4fe83e8be749c75cb08275e95da47138

Any idea where the problem would be?

Thanks,

Anurag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you currently can't fix that, it's a Facebook bug and it has been filed. If you know that it's a 1-to-1 conversation, you can handle the misbehavior by redirecting to `/message/(user_id)` instead of linking to the Thread URL. This is working for me.

To detect whether it's 1:1, query (FQL) the `recipients` array of `thread` and determine its size.

So with this work-around, you can't completely handle the bug, but you can reduce its impact!

Answer (score 0):

The URLs `http://www.facebook.com/messages/other/?action=read&tid=id.[user_id]` and `http://www.facebook.com/messages/?action=read&tid=id.[user_id]` works for me. You would only get an error if you don't have permission to access the conversation / thread.

Comment: What will be the URL when its a group chat?

Comment: Did you try the two URL patterns with messages coming both from the 'old' and the 'new' message system?

Comment: Are you referring to thread_id obtained via unified_thread (new) and thread (old) tables? I am using the thread table to get the thread_id.