# How to get facebook message thread URL knowing the thread id?

Tags: facebook

When I get a facebook thread id, how do I construct a link of the thread?

I have read [How to get message thread URL knowing the thread id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051642/how-to-get-message-thread-url-knowing-the-thread-id) and http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7747622/how-can-i-construct-a-link-to-view-a-message-on-facebook-com-if-i-have-the-messa

But in my inbox, there are some links like this:
http://m.facebook.com/messages#!/messages/read/?tid=mid.1359355288168%3A7e24f2d9dd97e7c323&__user=1388422425

What does *mid* mean?
Most of threads work with tid=id.xxxx or tid=xxx

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that not all inboxes and messages have been updated to the thread system. I have the same issue.

I assume that mid means Message ID as opposed to tid Thread ID